# How to save files using Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog with filenames longer than MAX_PATH?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, max-path

I am trying to save a file:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog
        {
            FileName = "verylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexampleverylongexample.foo",
            DefaultExt = ".foo",
            Filter = "Foo Bar|*.foo"
        };
```

Upon pressing Save in the dialog, I receive this:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

even though I have this in my `app.manifest`:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="https://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
      <ws2:longPathAware>
          true
      </ws2:longPathAware>
</windowsSettings>
```

as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Which version of Windows is what @dymanoid asked I believe.

Comment: Windows 10 Version 1803 Build 17134.471

Comment: Did you try the registry hack from that reference (just for completeness)?

Comment: @PaulSanders I set it through Group Policy

Comment: I can reproduce this issue using WIN32 API CreateFile2 on 1809 Windows 10 desktop and I'll report this issue via feedback hub.

Comment: Feedback hub issue: https://aka.ms/AA4g4r4 You can check and vote up it.

Answer (score -1):

So yes, what guys mentioned in the comments means that your Windows doesn't support it.

> Starting in Windows 10, *version 1607*, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions.

Now, to make it cross-Windows, you'd have to create custom file dialog, operating through paths using `\\?\Drive:\` style.